# Do S3 lifecycle policies generate events?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to add a lifecycle policy for my bucket to transition objects from Standard storage to Standard-IA storage. I have a Lambda, which is triggered by S3 events and I don't want to run it during object transition.
I don't use S3 objects versioning (I plan to use it in future with Replication feature).

I checked AWS documentation but I found nothing related to S3 events generation during transition.

Does S3 generates any event during transition?
If yes, please let me know what events it generates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 transition never generates any events. There is no events also for object deletion during transition (like Michael mentioned: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html).

I think before that I need to wait 30 days before transition but it has done overnight for files created earlier than 30 days ago :)

Comment: These have been updates since this answer was given: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-event-notifications.html

Answer (score 1):

The [supported notification types for Amazon S3 Event Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#supported-notification-event-types) are:

- `s3:ObjectCreated` (Put, Post, Copy)
- `s3:ObjectRemoved`
- `s3:ReducedRedundancyLostObject`

<strike>The only one of these that might be triggered during S3 Lifecycle events would be `s3:ObjectRemoved`, if the lifecycle is configured to delete objects.</strike> Transitioning between storage classes, or to Glacier, does not trigger `s3:ObjectCreated` (because the object already exists).

You can always test it for yourself by triggering transitions and seeing when your Lambda function is called.

When creating the event, you can also configure what type of activity (from the above list) triggers the notification.

Comment: [*"You will not receive event notifications from automatic deletes from lifecycle policies"*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)